# diffrence between implicit decleration of object type and explicit generic decleration

Tags: java, object, generics, type-safety

I can't understand the difference between the two code snippets below. Can someone help me with a simple explanation?
When we should use them?

If someone can help me with a simple explanation  I'll appreciate.

```
//1
List list1=new ArrayList();
for(Object obj:list1){}

//2
List<Object>list2=new ArrayList();
for(Object obj:list2){}
```

Comment: What language is this?  Please tag the question as such.

Answer (score 1):

Generics comes with Java5 and the main idea of this is to avoid the well know exception ClassCastException. In your example, before Java5 we were used to iterate collections of object and casting it's on runtime, so the exception mentioned above happened very often.

With Generics this kind of runtime exception became a compile time exception and you are be able to realized these errors early. In your example you can choice if you want to handle this situation as a runtime error (option 1) or compilation error (option 2) and realize how easier is to handle it in the option 2.

Generics is more than just implicit or explicit declaration, you should take a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 0):

`List` and `List<Object>` are similar (in that you can add any type to them) but different things .

`List` is a raw type and i can say `List l  =new ArrayList<Integer>()` or `List l  =new ArrayList()`.

But for `List<Object>` ,i can only assign `List` implementation of `Object` type. I can't say `List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();` .